# Axios route requests using parameters is returning 404

Tags: express, routes, axios, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to hit this route:

```
app.post("/api/score/:id-:name-:score", (req,res) => {
  //Do stuff
})
```

With the following code request

```
export default{
    AddNewScore: async(targetQuiz, newName, newScore) => {
        return axios.post(`api/score/${targetQuiz._id}-${newName}-${newScore}`).then(payload =>{
            return payload;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    } 
}
```

But I a get a 404 error whenever this request is made. I have been able to send other requests to my API routes, so it's not a problem with front-end/back-end connectivity.

Update:

Here's some more code from the routes file:

Here's a route that works:

```
app.get("/api/quizlist", (req,res) => {
  console.log("Recieved Request");
  db.QuizData.find().then(data => {
    console.log("Passed Data");
    res.json(data);
  }).catch(err => {
    res.json(err);
  });
});
```

Here's the code that's supposed to handle CORS:

```
app.use("*", async (req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localapp.com:3000")
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization")
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true)
  next()
})
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to be a parameters problem. I did a test with a post method with no parameters and got the same results.

Comment: Are you sure your route is actually getting defined? Can you share more code in that file? Is it getting imported anywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "actually getting defined" or "imported anywhere".

Comment: This is a MERN project, if that helps.

Comment: Like what file is `app.post` called in. What's the code in that file?